# High resolution timer on the BeagleBone?

Tags: timer, beagleboard

Is there a high-resolution timer (microsecond resolution or better) available on the [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/bone) ([TI AM3358 ARM Cortex-A8](http://www.ti.com/product/am3358) based) development board?

Comment: You can use the Cortex A8 cycle counter, see here:
 [How to measure program execution time in ARM Cortex-A8 processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3247373)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, DMTIMER - see page 3729 of the [Sitara Arm Cortex A8 Technical Reference Manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73e/spruh73e.pdf).  It can accept a wide range of clock frequencies and has a programmable prescaler allowing values from 1 to 256.  For example, it has a precision of 37ns when fed a 27MHz clock with a prescaler of 1 (Table 20-1 in the manual).  However, if you're using an operating system chance are it's already utilizing that timer and you'll be dependent on the operating system for timing.

Comment: Just so you know, your link is broken.

Comment: Link seems fine. But maybe you should add a revision number or update/remove the page number. DMTIMER is on page 4436 of the current revision (December 2019).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do, in addition to the dedicated timers listed in other answers you can use the embedded PRU [Programmable Realtime Unit](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Programmable_Realtime_Unit_Subsystem) modules in this processor to do high speed timing.  In addition to the main CPU there's two embedded CPU cores capable of running at 200MHz with most instructions running in a single cycle (5ns).  Each core has a 32 bit cycle counter providing 5ns resolution.  In combination with the dedicated interrupt controller per core, these units allow incredible timing precision for capturing/generating events.

The effort required to configure and use the PRU will be much higher than using a dedicated timer.